# Ubuntu server log viewer cli

Tags: command-line, log

Does anyone have any recommendation of an CLI tool for ubuntu that works as a log viewer?

I know you can do like sudo cat /var/log/mail.log to read that specific log file.

But maybe there is a tool that has a cute cli interface for browsing all logs that say exist inside the /var/log folder and it's subfolders ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is such a tool

Read `man journalctl`

In my `~/.bashrc`, in order to save typing, I have

```
alias jc=journalctl
```

I use `jc -u postfix.service` to look at my mailer logs.

`jc -h`, `jc --fields`, `jc  --field=FIELD` will show what you can ask `journalctl` about on YOUR system.

I also use "journalctl parenthesis". In `~/.bashrc`:

```
# tsjou "18-11-01 01:55:28" for journalctl --since
alias tsjou="date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"

# record beginning for journalctl
alias jstart="JSTART_TIME=\"\$(tsjou)\""
#show journal since `jstart`
alias jend="journalctl --since=\"\$JSTART_TIME\""
```

Then, just BEFORE I "do it" (connect the device or other action that creates log entries):

```
jstart
```

Then, I do the thing, wait a couple of seconds for the logs to "settle", and

```
jend
```

will show me everything that been logged since `jstart`

`jc /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to see what's up with networking.

One of my systems has been crashing (turned out to be power distribution). I use `jc -b -1 -e` to look at the end of the logs of the previous boot, in the hope of finding a commonality among the crashes. The lack of such a commonality was what led me to power.

`jc --follow` will follow the journal in near real time.

Looking through my `bash` history, I find I've used:

```
jc -b  _PID=1452 _PID=2772 _PID=2773
jc --since="14:25"
jc --since="2017-11-27 14:24:00" --until="2017-11-27 14:26:00" 
jc --since="-30 minutes"
jc --since="$(tsjou --date="09:30")"
jc --since="$(tsjou --date="march 28 09:55:00")"
```

Comment: @Kulfy updated, with exmples and hints

Comment: @luxwarp: Did my updated answer help? If so, please click the checkmark to accept my answer, so I'll gain reputatiion points and eventually Rule the World.

Comment: @waitinator Oh! Thank you so much! You got accepted ;)